# Unable to serve CSS File

Tags: html, css, http, go, gorilla

I am trying to connect my css file with my gohtml template however, I am not able to link it on the admin.go where the main function is located at. I have tried from one of the solutions here with gorilla mux however, I am still not able to connect. Can anyone assist me in this?

[The directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHYBo.png)
The gohtml template is located in the LoginPage Folder

In the func() main

```
r := mux.NewRouter()

r.PathPrefix("/CSS/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/CSS/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("LoginPage/CSS/"))))
```

GoHTML Href Link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/style.css" />
```

Comment: File paths are relative to the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).   Is the application's working directory the parent of the LoginPage directory?

Comment: @CeriseLimón Helllo, mm the LoginPage folder directory is on the same path as the Admin.go file. The LoginPage just holds the templates and css file needed.

Comment: Where the go files are located is completely irrelevant. The only thing that matters is which directory you're in when starting the server (which we call the application's working directory). If this isn't clear, inspect the return value of `os.Getwd()`. That path is prepended to the argument to http.Dir to build the filename.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the css directory path to `./LoginPage/CSS/`.

```
r.PathPrefix("/CSS/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/CSS/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./LoginPage/CSS/"))))
```